# Heroku how to commit to the heroku repo

Tags: git, heroku, heroku-cli

If I run this command

```
git remote -v

heroku  https://git.heroku.com/something.git (fetch)
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/something.git (push)
origin  https://jone@bitbucket.org/jone/something.git (fetch)
origin  https://jone@bitbucket.org/jone/something.git (push)
```

If I push something it goes to the bitbucket's repo. How do I push to the heroku repo?

Answer (score 2):

From Heroku Cli add your local heroku

```
heroku git:remote something
```

The branch you want to push is called 'heroku' so this should now work:

```
git push heroku master
```